# Can i call 'cancel()' on previous method inside setOnClickListener?

Tags: java, android

I'm making a simple quiz app that consist of 10 questions with 10sec countdown timer each questions. The scoring works while each questions answer correctly multiply by remaining time on CountDownTimer method, so it will be: score = answer * timeLeft; I successfully took a value of timeLeft from CountDownTimer. I set while the time over, it automatically intent to next question. The problem is when i choose the correct answer and tap the next button it succesfully took the timeLeft value and multiply it with 1 (each correct answer will be 1point), but the countdown timer still goes by until over, so when i already move to another question by tapping next button, the time on previous question still running and when its over unfortunately it move to previous question which the time not over yet. How could i call cancel() from CountDownTimer method inside setOnClickListener?

```
    public void setTimer() {                                                        

    //Initialize a new CountDownTimer instance                                  
   new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture,countDownInterval){                        

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){                           
                //do something in every tick                                        
                //Display the remaining seconds to app interface                    
                //1 second = 1000 milliseconds                                      
                cDown.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);                     
                timeLeft = millisUntilFinished / 1000;                              

            }                                                                       
            public void onFinish(){                                                 
                //Do something when count down finished                             
                cDown.setText("NEXT!");                                             
                Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity1.this,TestActivity2.class); 
                intent.putExtra("score", score);                                    
                startActivity(intent);                                              
                finish();                                                           
                timeLeft = 0;                                                       
            }                                                                       


        }.start();                                                                  

        bNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                       

            @Override                                                               
            public void onClick(View v) {                                           

                cancel();                                                           

                timeLeft = millisUntilFinished;                                     
                Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity1.this,TestActivity2.class); 
                intent.putExtra("score", score);                                    
                startActivity(intent);                                              
                finish();                                                           
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);         

            }                                                                       

        });                                                                         

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store a variable for your countdown timer, so that it can be called and cancelled.

```
final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture,countDownInterval){......}
timer.start();

bNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                       

   @Override                                                               
   public void onClick(View v) {                                                   
     timer.cancel();
           .........
   }                                                                       

});
```

Comment: Nice one sir. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating it as `new CountDownTimer` directly,
first define a global variable like   `CountDownTimer cd`

Then you can use the methods of cd whereever you want.